# Does casting away the volatile keyword make sense here?

Tags: c++, arduino, volatile

I have a class instances of which are used with and without the volatile keyword:

```
class C {};
volatile C v_c;
C nv_c;
```

Now I came up with the following construct to write methods which work for both, volatile and non-volatile instances:

```
class C {
    public:
        void method() { methodQualified(false); };
        void method() volatile { methodQualified(); };
    private:
        void methodQualified(bool volatileSelf = true) volatile {
            auto& nqThis = volatileSelf ? *this : *const_cast<C*>(this);                
            // Do stuff with nqThis
        }
};
```

But now I wonder if/how the `methodQualified(false)` call will change the compilers behaviour for method calls on volatile/non-volatile instances. Does this construct make sense? The basic idea is to only have the potential performance penalty of using volatile where necessary. This is code written for Arduino.

Comment: You can check the generated code to see what the compiler does. [The compiler explorer](godbolt.org/) could do it online.

Comment: Why do you need it to be volatile in the first place? putting volatile to cast it away later seems strange...

Comment: @OznOg I have a class that represents data that is accessed from an ISR and main code (so I use volatile instances) and in other places the instances are just accessed from main code (so no volatile necessary).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thx, I tried to find something out with godbolt, but need some help with it. What compiler should I choose when developing for Arduino on ESP8266? I chose [ARM gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/fOSIKT) for a start, and it looks as if the same code is used for volatile and non-volatile access. Can someone with more insight in this confirm this?

Comment: @x-ray no, it doesn't makes sense, `auto` is still **compile-time** type, it has only one type. (well, type exist only at compile time, but hope you get my point)

Comment: @appleapple I know that. The question is: Can the compiler optimize the code in `methodQualified` that uses `nqThis` as if the method was not marked `volatile` when being called from a non-volatile context (where the volatile qualifier will explicitly be cast away)?

Comment: @x-ray you don't know that, then. There is **single** `void methodQualified(bool) volatile`, and a dynamic variable **cannot** change type of `volatileSelf`